# How to make dependent multilevel DropDown in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to make dependent multilevel dropdown first contains states list and second contains cities list, all the data fetched from API. Initially, I load state dropdown, when I select the state then cities of that state load if I select city, the city selected successfully but when I change the state value then an error occurs. What is the right way to reload the second dropdown if changes will make in the first dropdown?

Error: There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Instance of 'City'. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

```
Future _state;
Future _city;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _state = _fetchStates();
  }
```

```
Future<List<StateModel>> _fetchStates() async {
    final String stateApi = "https://dummyurl/state.php";
    var response = await http.get(stateApi);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<StateModel> listOfUsers = items.map<StateModel>((json) {
        return StateModel.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfUsers;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }
```

```
  Future<List<City>> _fetchCities(String id) async {
    final String cityApi = "https://dummyurl/city.php?stateid=$id";
    var response = await http.get(cityApi);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      print(items);
      List<City> listOfUsers = items.map<City>((json) {
        return City.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfUsers;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }
```

State Dropdown

```
FutureBuilder<List<StateModel>>(
                                        future: _state,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            AsyncSnapshot<List<StateModel>> snapshot) {
                                          if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                            return CupertinoActivityIndicator(animating: true,);
                                          return DropdownButtonFormField<StateModel>(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            decoration: spinnerDecoration('Select your State'),
                                            items: snapshot.data
                                                .map((countyState) => DropdownMenuItem<StateModel>(
                                              child: Text(countyState.billstate),
                                              value: countyState,
                                            ))
                                                .toList(),
                                            onChanged:(StateModel selectedState) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                stateModel = selectedState;
                                                _city = _fetchCities(stateModel.billstateid);
                                              });
                                            },
                                            value: stateModel,
                                          );
                                        }),
```

City Dropdown

```
FutureBuilder<List<City>>(
                                        future: _city,
                                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                                            AsyncSnapshot<List<City>> snapshot) {
                                          if (!snapshot.hasData)
                                            return CupertinoActivityIndicator(animating: true,);
                                          return DropdownButtonFormField<City>(
                                            isDense: true,
                                            decoration: spinnerDecoration('Select your City'),
                                            items: snapshot.data
                                                .map((countyState) => DropdownMenuItem<City>(
                                              child: Text(countyState.billcity)
                                                .toList(),
                                            onChanged: (City selectedValue) {
                                              setState(() {
                                                cityModel = selectedValue;
                                              });
                                            },
                                            value: cityModel,
                                          );
                                        }),
```

```
class StateModel {
  String billstateid;
  String billstate;
  String billcountryid;

  StateModel({this.billstateid, this.billstate, this.billcountryid});

  StateModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    billstateid = json['billstateid'];
    billstate = json['billstate'];
    billcountryid = json['billcountryid'];
  }
}
```

```
class City {
  String billcityid;
  String billcity;
  String billstateid;

  City({this.billcityid, this.billcity, this.billstateid});

  City.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    billcityid = json['billcityid'];
    billcity = json['billcity'];
    billstateid = json['billstateid'];
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make `cityModel = null` in `onChanged`  callback of State dropdown.

```
setState(() {
  cityModel = null;
  stateModel = selectedState;
  _city = _fetchCities(stateModel.billstateid);
});
```

> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value:
>   Instance of 'City'. Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were
>   detected with the same value

This error occurs here, because the `value` you are passing not in the `items` of `DropdownButtonFormField`(city dropdown).

When you select a State, you are fetching new list of city list and passing it to CityDropDown but forgot to clear the previously selected city(`cityModel`).

You can also refer this example: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/5dd318e491031df8b31a8fc7f2fbe320)

Comment: Thank you so much it is working,  I want to know is this is the correct way which I follow when working with dependent dropdown

Comment: @Toyed If you want to show the loading indicator in place of `CityDropDown` until you select or change the `StateDropDown`, then its good to go with two `FutureBuilder`. But I prefer to show the loading dialog instead of replacing the `CityDropDown` like in the DartPad I shared.

Comment: Ok..according to this way which I follow I am facing a problem until new state data is not fetched It is showing previous state data.

Comment: @Toyed Its because you are using `!snapshot.hasData` condition. Try changing it to `snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting`

Comment: Yes, Now Working Fine, You are so genius. Thanks a lott

Comment: Can you please help me how can I solve this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809654/how-can-i-get-data-using-provider

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing a problem until new state data is not fetched It is showing previous state data. The approach I have used is different. I am not using future Builders. 
Here is My code:

```
               Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Container(
                          width: 450,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Source",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              source1 != null ? DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                isExpanded: true,
                                validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null,
                                hint: Text("Select Source"),
                                items: source1.data.map((item) {
                                  // print("Item : $item");
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: item.descr,
                                    child: Text(item.descr),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String cat) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    subsourseStr = null;
                                    sourceStr = cat;
                                    getSubSource2(sourceStr);
                                  });
                                },
                                value: sourceStr,
                              ):SizedBox(height: 10),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
//
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Container(
                          width: 450,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Sub Source",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              subSource2 != null ? DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                                isExpanded: true,
                                validator: (value) => value == null ? 'field required' : null,
                                hint: Text("Select Sub Source"),
                                items: subSource2.data.map((item) {
                                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                    value: item.descr,
                                    child: Text(item.descr),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                                onChanged: (String cat) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    subsourseStr = cat;
                                  });
                                },
                                value: subsourseStr,
                              ):SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```