# How can I get data using provider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am implementing login with provider but I am not getting data on dashboard page.
**Model Class**

```
class LoginModel {
Data data;
int status;
String message;

LoginModel({this.data, this.status, this.message});

LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
status = json['status'];
message = json['message'];
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
if (this.data != null) {
  data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
}
data['status'] = this.status;
data['message'] = this.message;
return data;
 }
}

 class Data {
  String customerId;
  String customerMobileNo;
  String customerToken;
  String otp;

  Data({this.customerId, this.customerMobileNo, this.customerToken, this.otp});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   customerId = json['customerId'];
   customerMobileNo = json['customerMobileNo'];
  customerToken = json['customerToken'];
  otp = json['otp'];
 } 

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  data['customerId'] = this.customerId;
  data['customerMobileNo'] = this.customerMobileNo;
  data['customerToken'] = this.customerToken;
  data['otp'] = this.otp;
  return data;
  }
 }
```

Provider Class

```
class AuthProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
Future<LoginModel> generateOTP(String mobileNumber) async {
var result;
Response response = await post(
  AppUrl.login,
  body: {
    'mobileNo': mobileNumber,
  },
);
if(response.statusCode==200) {
  final responseData = json.decode(response.body);
  var userData = responseData['data'];
  print(responseData);
  LoginModel authUser = LoginModel.fromJson(userData);
  notifyListeners();
}
else {
  print("Something went wrong");
}
return result;
}
}
```

Display Page

```
 class Dashboard extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 final userTest = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
 return Scaffold(
   body: Center(
    child: ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      children: [
               Text(userTest.authUser.data.customerToken),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

Error

The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
The getter 'customerToken' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: customerToken

How can I access the property of LoginModel class. Can anyone solve my query please help me, I tried  a lott but I can not get value.

Answer (score 0):

1. `LoginModel authUser = LoginModel.fromJson(userData);` you are initializing value to method variable `LoginModel authUser` not a class variable `authUser` try removing `LoginModel` from before 'authUser'.
2. In `Dashboard` you should also check for `null` value, you can do that like this `userTest?.authUser?.data?.customerToken ?? ''`

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot notify your listeners with normal Future functions (though, I am not sure because you didn't provide the full code of your provider class). You will have to put your `generateOTP()` function in a [changenotifier](/questions/tagged/changenotifier) class that will help you to notify your listeners whenever required and make it scoped to your widget.
2. You are getting this error because you are not storing your token anywhere or you are not invoking your storage token before using it. So first, please try to store your token and invoke it before using it.

Comment: I putted ```generateOTP()``` function inside class which is ```extends``` with ```ChangeNotifier``` but I did not mention it in sample code.

Comment: @Jorden, then surly you are not invoking your token before using it. I will prefer you to store your token on local storage and then invoke it before using. According to your question, for access to your model, firstly make authuser(an instance of LoginModel) global to AuthProvider class and return your authUser instead of result. May it help you. Thank you.